# Decreasing the size of see-what-you-type program

Tags: assembly, x86, size, hex, byte

```
B8 00 B8 8E E8 B4 00 CD 16 65 88 00 EF F2
```

The program initially had 16 bytes, but I decided, to sacrifice 2 bytes in favor of unstable input position. Here is the previous version (0 0 position):

```
65 88 06 00 00
```

Then the possible candidate was:

```
EF F2 -> 
C3 ->
CF..CB..CC..CE
```

Those one-byters were also no-helpers. 
My faint thought is to change (not use) the segment component. Remove 65 and use default data segment. Unfortunately it seems it doesn't work.

What I'm doing wrong? Yesterday I decreased my module to 13 byte size, though it was unstable so far that every symbol appeared in a separate screen position.

Comment: 1/ This question should be tagged “binary”, not “assembly”. 2/ Without an instruction set, it is impossible to tell what these codes do. Is this PowerPC code? MIPS? ARM? 16-bit x86? 32-bit x86? x86_64?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's clearly 16-bit real mode x86 code, a .com file for DOS or other flat binary.

```
$echo 'B8 00 B8 8E E8 B4 00 CD 16 65 88 00 C3' | udcli -x -16

0000000000000000 b800b8           mov ax, 0xb800          
0000000000000003 8ee8             mov gs, ax              
0000000000000005 b400             mov ah, 0x0             
0000000000000007 cd16             int 0x16                
0000000000000009 658800           mov [gs:bx+si], al      
000000000000000c c3               ret
```

It supposes that `bx` and `si` have some acceptable values, so that `0xb800:bx+si` points to the video memory region that's used by the current text video mode. Well, it's possible, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Anyway, it can be made at least 4 bytes shorter, if assumptions on register values are still allowed. If it can be assumed that `bx` and `si` have useful values (see above), then `di` probably too, so that `0xb800:di` points to the video memory region that's used by the current text video mode.

```
00000000  B800B8            mov ax,0xb800
00000003  8EC0              mov es,ax
00000005  98                cbw
00000006  CD16              int 0x16
00000008  AA                stosb
00000009  C3                ret
```

First set `ax` to `0xb800` and store the it to `es` (the segment address of several BIOS text video modes).

Then convert the byte `al` (0) to word `ax`, extending the sign bit of `al` to `ax`, resulting in `ax` = 0.

Then read input from keyboard (and wait for input, if necessary) with BIOS keyboard interrupt `int 16h` (`ah` = 0). ASCII code in `al`, scan code in `ah`.

Finally store the ASCII code to video memory (to `[es:di]`) with `stosb` to print the character on screen, and return to DOS (or whatever OS) with `ret`.

**Edit:** Actually it is possible to drop the size to 12 bytes and still have a stable output address, with something like this:

```
00000000  6800B8            push word 0xb800
00000003  1F                pop ds
00000004  31C0              xor ax,ax
00000006  CD16              int 0x16
00000008  A20000            mov [0x0],al
0000000B  C3                ret
```

Hope this helps.