# How I can optimize this code more? [Assembly 8086 letters pyramid]

Tags: optimization, assembly, x86

I wonder how I could optimize this code a little bit more. Now he has 467k and 59 lines.

Data segment:

```
code_char db 'A'
counter_space db 39
counter_char dw 1
counter_rows dw 25
```

Program segment:

```
rows:

mov cl, counter_space ;here I write space
mov ah,02h
mov dl,''
space:
int 21h
loop space

mov cx, counter_char ;here I write letters
mov ah,02h
mov dl,code_char
letters:
int 21h
loop letters

mov ah,02h   ;here I go to another line(enter)
mov dl,0ah
int 21h

INC code_char    ;here I change the value of variable's
DEC counter_space
ADD counter_char,2
DEC counter_rows

mov cx,counter_rows ;here I count the rows to 25 
loop rows

mov ah,01h ;here I w8 to any key
int 21h

            mov     ah,4ch
            mov     al,0
            int     21h
```

If you have any suggestions please comment.
I just started to learn Assembly.

Comment: Do you aim to optimize for speed or for size? What assembler you are using? And what command-line parameters you are using for the assembler? The code looks like 16-bit code for MS-DOS enviroment (`int 21h` and so on), so it's quite obsolete. If using 16-bit code is not a requirement given by a teacher and you don't aim to write your own bootloader now, I'd suggest you to learn modern 32-bit or 64-bit x86/x86-64 assembly instead of obsolete 16-bit x86 assembly.

Comment: I has to optimize for size(lines,memory).You are right its 16 bit for MS-DOS enviroment). I have to use 16-bit.

Comment: What assembler and what command-line arguments you are using? What do you mean with `(lines, memory)`? In my opinion, optimizing for code lines does not make much sense for assembly code. If you really need to, just write all the code using `db`, you get only only 1 line of code... Do you mean the size of your EXE file is 467 kilobytes? If you really need to optimize for executable size, make your executable a COM file. And after that check the sizes of encodings of all instructions in your code and look for places to make the executable shorter.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243738/decreasing-the-size-of-see-what-you-type-program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the fact that all other variables can be calculated from the `counter_rows` variable, so you really only need one variable:

```
code_char     = 'A' + 25 - counter_rows
counter_space = counter_rows + 14
counter_char  = 51 - counter_rows * 2
```

As `counter_rows` is your outer loop counter, you can just keep it in a register all the time instead of allocating memory for it. That makes it possible to run the program without any memory references at all.

There are some other small optimisations that can be done. You don't need to set the `ah` register to `02h` other than for the first call. When setting `ah` to `01h` for the keypress call, you can just decrement the register as you know that it was `02h` before. You can set `ax` instead of setting `ah` and `al` separately.

If I counted correctly, this should take the actual code and data bytes down from 59 to 41:

```
mov bx, 25 ;counter_rows
rows:

  ;here I write space
  mov cx, bx ; counter_space = counter_rows + 14
  add cl, 14
  mov ah, 02h
  mov dl, 32 ;space
  space:
    int 21h
  loop space

  ;here I write letters
  mov cl, 51 ;counter_char = 51 - counter_rows * 2
  sub cl, bl
  sub cl, bl
  ;mov ah, 02h - already set
  mov dl, 65 + 25 ;code_char = 'A' + 25 - counter_rows
  sub dl, bl
  letters:
    int 21h
  loop letters

  ;here I go to another line(enter)
  ;mov ah, 02h - already set
  mov dl, 0ah
  int 21h

  dec bx
jnz rows

;here I wait for any key
dec ah ;02h - 1 = 01h
int 21h

mov ax,4c00h ;set ah and al in one go
int 21h
```